Acquiring the Vietnam e-visa while already in Phu Quoc
I arrived in Phu Quoc with the 30 day visa exemption. Am I allowed to apply for the e-visa while I’m already here? I’d like to use the e-visa to go from Phu Quoc to mainland Vietnam.

Asked a few local tour guides but they have no definitive answer. They’re leaning towards ‘not possible’. If it’s not possible, one has to fly out to a different country after arriving with the visa exempt scheme.
